# COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderXXXXXXXX/java-common/ug-common/src: no such file or directory

Tags: docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

I am having following error when copying the file. Why is that?

```
docker-compose up



COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderXXXXXXX/java-common/ug-common/src: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever file / directory you're trying to copy into your image doesn't exist in your build context. Set `context` to a directory that contains everything you need and `dockerfile` to the path of your dockerfile within it.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file#build